# Google Task Manager Custom Events are not triggering - Android

Tags: android, events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-events

I have implemented google task manager for custom events triggering, i have followed each and every step mentioned in the [google doc](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/) but thing are not working, events are not logged in the google analytics dashboard. If any one have implemented it before kindly help us done with that task.

```
    TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
    tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);

    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending =
            tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault("GTM-YOUR-KEY",
                    R.raw.gtm_your_key);

    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {

            Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
            if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("CuteAnimals", "failure loading container");
                //displayErrorToUser(R.string.load_error);
                return;
            }
            containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerHolder.ContainerAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onContainerAvailable(ContainerHolder containerHolder, String s) {

                    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDataLayer();
                    // pushing event here

                }
            });
            containerHolder.refresh();

        }
    }, 15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, have you checked your container this must be an issue of google tag manager container, Check your container Event Value it should be a number, not a string. Shuffle the values, for example - Action - Click on: {{GTM - Click Target}}, Label - {{GTM - Click Value}}, and leave the value empty, this will fix your problem.

Comment: Yes this is the exact issue i have faced, i am done with that issue, anyways thanks for your reply.